# How do i convert a 128_t binary hex to decimal in eosjs?

Tags: eosjs

I have the value: `200000000000000000000000000000` which is represented as: `0x00000040952fe4da5c1f3c8602000000` that i'm trying to convert in `eosjs`.

`signedBinaryToDecimal(hexToUint8Array("0x00000040952fe4da5c1f3c8602000000"), 0))` seems to fail with `"Error: Expected hex string"`

Has anyone managed to do this?

Answer (score 3):

`0x` is a flag for compilers to know that it's a hex value. This isn't required for hexToUint8Array();